# how to pass in array in procedure call in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a procedure that takes in an array in postgres, this syntax works:

`SELECT * from myMethod(array['test','test'], array[''], 554, 73430, 322234, 'shazam');`

the array keyword is what I am referring to. this works in postgres but I cannot find the documentation to understand how this work in oracle. how do i pass in arrays to function call?

the error when running the above is:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 38
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the database version; whether you have created a type called `ARRAY` (as it doesn't exist natively); and the DDL (`CREATE FUNCTION`) statement for `myMethod` as, apart from the obvious syntax errors of `[]` rather than `()`, a lot of the problems are going to come down to what the signature of the function is and what it is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

and create your function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION myMethod(
  p_words    IN array,
  p_suffixes IN array,
  p_value1   IN INT,
  p_value2   IN INT,
  p_value3   IN INT,
  p_prefix   IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN array PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  value VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_words.COUNT LOOP
    value := p_prefix || p_words(i);
    FOR j IN 1 .. p_suffixes.COUNT LOOP
      value := value || p_suffixes(j);
    END LOOP;
    PIPE ROW ( value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```sql
SELECT * from myMethod(array('test1','test2'), array('ab','cd'), 554, 73430, 322234, 'shazam');
```

In earlier Oracle versions, you may need to use:

```sql
SELECT * from TABLE( myMethod(array('test1','test2'), array('ab','cd'), 554, 73430, 322234, 'shazam') );
```

and it outputs:

> ```
> | COLUMN_VALUE    |
> | :-------------- |
> | shazamtest1abcd |
> | shazamtest2abcd |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d64276d8d1757f0f30efa595c63c5f3)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example; I'm using built-in `sys.odcivarchar2list` type. You'd use your own (if this doesn't suit your needs).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_arr (par_array in sys.odcivarchar2list) is
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line(par_array(1));
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_arr(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B'));
A                                               

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: you you're saying from that example the correct sytnax is to use 

    array('a','b')? 

doesnt seem to work

Comment: It depends on what your real case is. As you can see, **my example** works.